# Schedule jobs outside Kernel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to schedule jobs from other parts of the code. So I created my own scheduler class which gets `Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule::class` injected as constructor parameter. The scheduler class is resolved with `app(..::class)`.

Everything works fine however jobs scheduled on this instance are never actually scheduled.

One idea was maybe registering the `Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule` as singleton.

Ex.:

```
class JobA extends Job
{
  private $taskList;

  public function __construct(TaskList $taskList)
  {
    $this->taskList = $taskList;
  }

  public function handle()
  {
    $this->taskList->run();
  }
}

class TaskList
{
  private $tasks = [
    TaskA::class,
    TaskB::class,
    ...
  ];

  public function run()
  {
    foreach($this->tasks as $task) {
      // resolve $task and call it's own run method..  
    }
  }

  public function addToSchedule(Schedule $schedule)
  {
    $scheduler->job(new JobA($this))->everyFiveMinutes();  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule` class is already defined as a [Singleton](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/0e25a0bba89fade1b5d4f4397d81eb1fad53fd2f/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php#L100). What would be interesting to understand is that when you say **other parts of your code**, do you refer to the request lifecycle code or console code? Both have different Kernels and different applications and scheduling was meant to be part of the Console / CLI part of Laravel

Comment: I noticed that after some debugging seems all jobs are added but not executed I have to investigate further.

Comment: Keep in mind that your crontab executes the `Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\ScheduleRunCommand::handle` method. At the time this execution happens, your jobs must be registered

Comment: see my added example. I have TaskScheduler (gets Schedule instance) resolves TaskList class and calls addToSchedule passing the Schedule instance. The TaskList adds it self to the schedule. Well schedules JobA to run every 5 minutes. JobA calls run method on the received instance of TaskList.

Comment: I can see that jobs get scheduled but never queued or executed. In JobA handle method I have logger(..) & cache(..) to see if it ever gets called but nothing stored to log or cache.

Comment: Does TaskList extend Schedule or do you have another class for that?

Comment: Or perhaps you meant `$schedule->job...`

Comment: fixed. I meant `$schedule->job` checked again.

Comment: Dont understand how the execution reaches to Tasklist or JobA? Are any of these Artisan commands?

Comment: What's preventing you from adding `$schedule->job(new JobA...` in the `App\Console\Kernel::schedule` method?

Comment: I have a command which collects some data then based on data chosen to be collected creates & runs one of the *Scheduler classes. These than create TaskList and schedule it to run at a certain point. Everything works well up to the addToSchedule method. Job is added to the schedule but it's handle method never called.

Comment: The thing is that the crontab is registered to the `ScheduleRunCommand::handle` method. When this is executed, your command is not running and so the `Schedule` class does not have your jobs registered. I guess if you want a dynamic job resolution, you would need a persistence layer, e.g. store the job name, time to run and data required to run in the database and in your Schedule class you may query the database to schedule dynamic tasks

Comment: Schedule is a singleton tho. It goes like this: I manually run my 'collect' command. This creates a TaskScheduler class (which gets Schedule injected), creates TaskList passes the reference this adds a job to the schedule. Maybe at this minute the Schedule does not contain the jobs but on next call of `ScheduleRunCommand::handle` it should no ?

Comment: Also weird why would it work setting schedule in Schedule injected in Kernel but not this class as it's the same instance.

Comment: The crontab runs `ScheduleRunCommand::handle` on a different `$app` instance. So it doesnt have the same jobs scheduled even though it is a singleton

Comment: It's like 2 PHP-CLI commands running independently and one wants the other's variables. Cant happen without a persistence layer! In fact, every call of `ScheduleRunCommand::handle` is a different `$app`!!

Comment: Why it works in `Schedule` injected in Kernel is because every $app that runs executes the `ScheduleRunCommand::handle` which in turn registers the jobs

Comment: Ah right. I'll have to figure out how to resolve this issue. I don't think Schedule class can be serialised maybe the events.